# ICredentialProvider in combination with DbContext BotFramework v4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, botframework

I am using a `MultiCredentialProvider` that implements the `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ICredentialProvider` interface. It works with [static values](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/9c1478595211a0de634d0f272032162c3a21934f/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Authentication/SimpleCredentialProvider.cs) but as soon as I try to pass a repository which uses a `DbContext` to retrieve my bot credentials, it fails with the following message.

`System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

This is caused because the repository should be scoped and not just passed to an object to use in a later stage. The repository is resolved in the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class.

```
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var repository = sp.GetService<SomeRepository>();

services.AddBot<SomeBot>(options => { 
         options.CredentialProvider = new MultiCredentialProvider(configuration, repository); 
    })
```

The question is, how can I resolve the service on demand to avoid this error? Is it possible to resolve the whole CredentialProvider, so I can make use of constructor injection? Anything else that I am missing here?

--

Update:
As a temporary workaround, I first get the credentials list from the database, then construct the object and pass the credentials to the `MultiCredentialProvider` constructor. The only problem with this is that everything is assigned at startup and cannot be changed at a later time. Still looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up writing a Func that gets invoked when the credentials are required. The values are cached so it's not an expensive lookup.

```
public class MultiCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly Func<Task<List<MultiBotCredential>>> _botCredentialsFunc;

        public MultiCredentialProvider(IConfiguration configuration, Func<Task<List<MultiBotCredential>>> botCredentialsFunc)
        {
            _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            _getBotCredentialsFunc = botCredentialsFunc;
        }

        public int BotId => _configuration.GetBotId();

        public async Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId)
        {
            var botCredentials = await _botCredentialsFunc.Invoke();
            var credential = botCredentials.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BotId == BotId);

            if (credential == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return credential.AppId.Equals(appId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your startup add your credential provider and db context to  the services collection.  Create your credential provider as a a scoped service and add to its constructor the db context so that it can be resolved from DI. Once your provider is resolving your dbcontext from dependency injection you can pass your credential provider to your bot and perform your logic within the credential provider to retrieve your creds from db.
You could optionally create a botid resolver that resolves the botid per request if you need something more robust than config...  perhaps add something to the pipeline that looks at route values.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //OtherServices
    // add your db context to services
    services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>();
    // setup your credential provider to resolve on every request -scoped
    services.AddScoped<ICredentialProvider, MultiCredentialProvider>();
    // optional create a BotIdResolver that can retrieve the botid at runtime per request for example resolve it from the route
    services.AddScoped<IBotIdResolver, ConfigIdResolver>();


}
public class MultiCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly YourDbContext  _db;
    private readonly BotIdResolver _resolver;

    public MultiCredentialProvider(IConfiguration configuration, YourDbContext db,IBotIdResolver botIdResolver = null)
    {
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        _db = db;
        _resolver = botIdResolver;
    }

    // optional replace with botIdResolver
    public int BotId => _configuration.GetBotId();

    public async Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId)
    {
        // optional use botIdResolver 
        //var id = _resolver.GetId();
        // work with  dbcontext
        //_db.
    }

}
```